# Read Data from Excel Without Importing Excel to Toad

Tags: excel, oracle, toad

I'm new in using toad. I have one "ID" column in Excel file which contains 1800 ids of Students.

I want to get Student Names of the ids in the Excel sheet from Student table in Toad.

```
Select StudenName from Student
Where StudentID = ID (ID should be taken from Excel)
```

Is it possible to read the ids from Excel in Toad without importing the Excel file to Toad?

Hope I clarified the question enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use UTL_FILE package to open a read from file

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF